# Create a named list, with the values as a character vector

Tags: r, list, vector

I am trying to create a named list in R where the contents of each named list element is a character vector of two values.

What I have is like this:

```
list_vec <- c('item1', 'item2', 'item3')
val_vec <- c(0.5, 3)
```

What I want is a list like this:

```
$item1
[1] 0.5  3

$item2
[1] 0.5  3

$item3
[1] 0.5  3
```

I've tried combinations of `as.list` and `setNames`, but I can't seem to find the right syntax. Ideally the solution would be base R or tidyverse please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the point is to repeat your `val_vec` (you have to make it a `list` at this stage) according to the `length` of `list_vec`.

```r
setNames(rep(list(val_vec), length(list_vec)), list_vec)
$item1
[1] 0.5 3.0

$item2
[1] 0.5 3.0

$item3
[1] 0.5 3.0
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Will accept once I'm allowed!

I found another way later on too:
mylist <- replicate(length(list_vec), val_vec, FALSE);
names(mylist) <- paste0(list_vec)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version with `replicate`.

```
replicate(length(list_vec), val_vec, simplify = FALSE) |> setNames(list_vec)

#$item1
#[1] 0.5 3.0

#$item2
#[1] 0.5 3.0

#$item3
#[1] 0.5 3.0
```

Or a simpler one with `sapply` where you don't need to assign the names explicitly :

```
sapply(list_vec, \(x) val_vec, simplify = FALSE)
```